# Dissalow all subdomains with nginx

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

How I can disallow all subdomains in robots.txt with nginx?
For example I want show simply:

`User-agent: *
Disallow: /`

For all my subdomains

Comment: And what did you try and why simple `robots.txt` file is not suitable for you?

Comment: I have about 50 dynamic subdomains and I want close for indexing all subdomains with nginx

Comment: How is it contradict to simple file?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my task:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /home/deploy/htdocs/robots.txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to set one `robots.txt` per subdomain, unfortunately.